# WebAPI2 Async ..is that compatible with all other languages out there?

Tags: c#, c++, ios, asp.net-web-api

I'm considering writing every single API call as ASYNC but I was wondering and I tested that on the client and works well.

**Question:**
But I'm wondering if any other language can handle that and what specific instruction each language needs to use in order to get the response accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only async on your server for those methods. Web Api just uses HTTP to do its work and is cross platform. There is nothing "async" about HTTP.

Comment: So what you saying is that the API will be called the same way and the waiting time might improve but no extra code will be needed on the client, right?  And also, is it standard or recommended to write async APIs?

Comment: @Developer correct. its recommended if you have other i/o bound behavior

Comment: @DanielAWhite Is Database data access considered "other" type of behaviour where async is recommended?

Comment: yea it can be - ado.net has async api's now